# Nginx: Skip HTTP Basic Authentication based on IP or request header

Tags: nginx

The `http` block in `nginx.conf` contains the following:

```
auth_basic $development_exceptions;
```

In an included file the `geo` module is used to set the variable:

```
geo $development_exceptions {
     default "Not allowed.";

    1.2.3.4 "off";
}
```

The `map` module uses the user agent variable in the same included file:

```
map $http_user_agent $development_exceptions  { 
    default "Not allowed.";

    ~*(header-text) "off";
}
```

However, the setting of the development exceptions variable is competing, and so when the second code is applied the first code stops doing anything.

How can both strategies be combined? In this case it might not be possible to change `nginx.conf`.

Comment: So you expect a solution and you don't want to change `nginx.conf` which controls what happens?

Comment: The structure at the host is setup in such a way that the includes can be controlled but not `nginx.conf`. If the only way to do this is through `nginx.conf`, then I am interested in that solution as well, as I can make a request for it.

Comment: The parts that you posted, can they be edited to workout a solution? Are those both part of the includes or they are directly in  nginx.conf?

Comment: They can be edited in any way, they are both part of the includes and not directly in nginx.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should try below approach

```
geo $development_exceptions_geo {
    default "Not allowed.";
    1.2.3.4 "off";
}

map $http_user_agent $development_exceptions_agent  { 
    default "Not allowed.";

    ~*(header-text) "off";
}
```

Now if you want to use `or` condition then you can do below

```
map $development_exceptions_agent$development_exceptions_geo $development_exceptions {
    ~off "off";
    default "Not allowed.";
}
```

If you want an `and` condition then you can do below

```
map $development_exceptions_agent$development_exceptions_geo $development_exceptions {
    ~offoff "off";
    default "Not allowed.";
}
```

Comment: Your 'or' code reads like xor. Correct?

I will try your solution and get back to you.

Comment: I read it wrong. Your `~off` is a regex and matches any 'off'. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to combine 'allowed IP-List' OR 'some User Agents' to bypass authentication, works:

```
geo $auth_geo {
    default "Authentication required";
    18.184.113.24 "off"; # pingdom
    35.158.65.6 "off";   # pingdom
    52.87.44.246 "off";  # url.thum.io
    52.44.29.90 "off";   # url2.thum.io
}

map $http_user_agent $auth_agent {
    default "Auth required";
    "~PingdomPageSpeed" "off";
    "~cutycapt" "off";
    "~Chrome-Lighthouse" "off";
}

map $auth_geo$auth_agent $auth {
    ~off "off";
    default "Not allowed.";
}
```

then use it similar to:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    auth_basic $auth;
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/custom/website/htpasswd;
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass $phpupstream;
}
```

I do not know if `auth_basic_user` can maybe also a relativ path (?).